# How to make first table view cell as static and then load data from second cell using swift

Tags: swift, cell, uitableview

```
class FiorstTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var data = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0{
            return 1
        }
        return data.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCellfortable") as! CheckTableViewCell
        cell.LabelNumber.text = data[indexPath.row]
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            print("my first cell")
        }
            return cell
    }
}
```

I need to load data from the second table view cell and making first cell as static.i have searched other stack overflow answers nothing works out for me..help me to do this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have two ways to implement that:**

**1)** You can make two cell for `UITableView` first one always return when `indexPath.row == 0`
and for all return your SecondCellfortable

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 50 //row count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCellfortable") as! CheckTableViewCellFirst
             cell.LabelNumber.text = data[indexPath.row]
             print("my first cell")
             return cell
        } else {
             tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondCellfortable") as! CheckTableViewCellSecond
             return cell
        }
}
```

**OR**

**2)** You can add the `UITableViewHeader`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.sectionHeaderHeight))
     view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
     // Do your customization
     return view
}
```

Comment: how to return in the func for  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
}

Comment: but when i scroll table view header should also want to move how to do that

Comment: See the updated answer for first, numberOfRowsInSection and the second one, I am unable to understand what do u want to say..?

Comment: for the first cell it should be static from second cell i want to load data

Comment: Yes when the cell index 0 then return firstCell otherwise it will return secondCell..

Comment: when the table view scrolls i want the first cell i.e..static cell also wants to scroll

Comment: am following your method only if indexpath.row == 0..only that condition is working remaining cells are blank\

Comment: i have done my customization i.e data[indexpath.row]..but not going through else statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136933/discussion-between-salman-ghumsani-and-user7333282).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have static and dynamic cells in the same tableview. I recommend setting up your "first table cell" as a UIView then setting the tableheaderview to your custom view.

```
    let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("YourCustomView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? YourCustomView
    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

Comment: can you explain little bit more